# Get SQL to run on specific inbound port range client side

Tags: c#, .net, sql, clickonce, firewall

I have a issue where an application I am writing (written in .net using C#) has started to be blocked by the firewall when making SQL connections, the reason seems to be the inbound port client side is coming in on a massive range that isn't allowed by the firewall (around port 50,000 - 60,000).

Is there a way to make SQL connections run on a specific inbound port range client side so this smaller port range can be added as a exception to the clients firewall? The server uses Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

I know one solution is to add the application itself to the firewall but the delployment method used at the company is Click Once and when it updates it changes the directory of the installed program meaning an admin has to update the firewall for each client every time an update is made.

Comment: You are connecting to a database inside your corporate network from the "outside world" ? If that's the case, you might want to consider moving the queries in a web service, and let it provide you the data (it'll be deployed on a specific, well-known port, so you'll be alright).

Comment: Cheers that's definitely viable if I can't find another solution.

Answer (score 1):

As I pointed out in my comment (quoting myself here), you might want to consider moving the queries in a web service, and let it provide you the data (it'll be deployed on a specific, well-known port, so you'll be alright).

More on the subject: I **strongly** recommend you *never* allow the outside world inside your corporate database, it's a big security issue.